# What is wrong with this Java code for Tennis Scoreboard

Tags: java

I am learning Java. I was able to build a simple basketball scorekeeper app and now and trying to figure out how to build a tennis scoreboard.

I cant figure out how to update the values of Team A for set 2 once Team A game reaches 6 points. It does update Set 1 once Team A game reaches 6

Here is the code

```
 Increase points on Team A */
public void incrementA(View view) {
    pointsTeamA = pointsTeamA + 1;
        {
            if (pointsTeamA == 1) displayA(15);
            if (pointsTeamA == 2) displayA(30);
            if (pointsTeamA == 3) displayA(40);
            if (pointsTeamA == 4) displayGamesA(gameTeamA = gameTeamA + 1);
            if (pointsTeamA == 4) displayA(pointsTeamA = 0);
            if (gameTeamA == 6) displaySet1A(gameTeamA);
            if (gameTeamA == 6) displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
            if (gameTeamA == 6) displaySet2A(gameTeamA);
            if (gameTeamA == 6) displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
        }
}
```

So far my methods are:

```
    /*This method displays points for Team A. */
    private void displayA(int number) { TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.points_team_A);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number); }

    /*This method displays games for Team A */
    private void displayGamesA(int number) { TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.game_score_team_A);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number); }


    /*This method displays Set 1 for Team A */
    private void displaySet1A(int number) { TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.set_1_team_A);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number); }

    /*This method displays Set 2 for Team A */
    private void displaySet2A(int number) { TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.set_2_team_A);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number); }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

I have all my `int` values set to zero such as `int gameTeamA = 0;`

**Last part of the project:**
Goal: when both player's score is 40, it displays "Deuce" then in order for Player A to win, it has to score 2 consecutive points, where point 1 will display "ADV" and point 2 will end game adding a score to gameTeamA and new game begins.

Code so far:

```
public void incrementA(View view) {
    pointsTeamA++;
    displayDeuceA(null);
    if (pointsTeamA == 1) displayA(15);
    if (pointsTeamA == 2) displayA(30);
    if (pointsTeamA == 3) displayA(40);
    if (pointsTeamA == 3 && pointsTeamB == 3)
        displayDeuceA("Deuce");
    if (pointsTeamA == 4) {
        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = gameTeamA + 1);
        displayA(pointsTeamA = 0);
        displayB(pointsTeamB = 0);
        displayDeuceA(null);
        displayDeuceB(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to create multi-line If statements instead of duplicating the same statement several times.

```
public void incrementA(View view) {
    pointsTeamA++;
    if (pointsTeamA == 1) displayA(15);
    if (pointsTeamA == 2) displayA(30);
    if (pointsTeamA == 3) displayA(40);

    if (pointsTeamA == 4) {
        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = gameTeamA + 1);
        displayA(pointsTeamA = 0);
    }
    if (gameTeamA == 6) {
        displaySet1A(gameTeamA);
        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
        displaySet2A(gameTeamA);
        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
    }

}
```

That being said, it's not entirely clear what you're referring to in your question until you provide us with the methods you used, so we can see what they are supposed to do. From what I can tell, everytime a score hits 6, you're updating the values for both Set 1 AND Set 2; I believe you should have an integer variable that keeps track of what set the game is on, and an if statement inside increment that updates values for a set depending on this variable.

**EDIT: Here is how it could be done**

First, create a static field in the class itself.

```
public static int set = 1;
```

Put this after your class declaration, outside of any methods.

```
public void incrementA(View view) {
    pointsTeamA++;
    if (pointsTeamA == 1) displayA(15);
    if (pointsTeamA == 2) displayA(30);
    if (pointsTeamA == 3) displayA(40);

    if (pointsTeamA == 4) {
        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = gameTeamA + 1);
        displayA(pointsTeamA = 0);
    }
    if (gameTeamA == 6) {
        if (set == 1) {
            displaySet1A(gameTeamA);
            displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
            set++; // Adds to the set variable, making it 2
        } else if (set == 2) {
            displaySet2A(gameTeamA);
            displayGamesA(gameTeamA = 0);
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit 2: For handling deuces, advantages, wins when the score is beyond 3. Replace your previous if-statement for pointsTeamA == 4**

```
if (pointsTeamA >= 4) {
    if (pointsTeamA - pointsTeamB >= 2) {   // if team A wins

        displayGamesA(gameTeamA = gameTeamA + 1);
        displayA(pointsTeamA = 0);
        displayB(pointsTeamB = 0);
        displayDeuceA(null);
        displayDeuceB(null);
   } else if (pointsTeamA - pointsTeamB == 1) { // score up by one

    // code for displaying "Advantage"  
   } else { // scores are tied
    // code for displaying "Deuce"
   }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added methods I have so far. I believe your logic is correct but I am not sure I am capable of writing such code...but I will try!!!

Comment: if you have any further advise i would appreciated it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have trouble of being 'incapable of writing such code'; all I did was take your code and format it better. Let me know if it still isn't working.

Comment: Thank you. Like you said your code looks better, which I appreciate as it teaches me how to make it look better, but it still gives me the same result of set 1 and set 2 = 6 at the same time when gameTeamA = 6....and because when gameTeamA = 6 .....ideally I would like for set 1 = gameTeamA if gameTeamA = 6 and set 2 = gameTeamA if gameTeamA = 6...as you see its the same thing....im not sure how to write the logic so that set 2 updates its values from gameTeamA only after set 1 has taken place.

Comment: Oh I see, you were saying you couldn't code the second part I was saying. Allow me a moment, I'll edit my answer to help.

Comment: Done. Feel free to ask me anything for clarification.

Comment: Thank you @Kartik It did the trick and I was able to do the same for set 3 and also for player B. There is one more thing before is all done. Not sure if you know how the tennis score works but basically in order for player A to win a set, it must win 2 games above player B. Example 6-4. But if game is at 5-5. It must end 7-5....same goes with the points. If 40-40. Player A would needs two points ahead in order to which such game.......I am going to do try my best to figure it out. Will post again if I need help in 48 hours or so. Thanks again!

Comment: I give up! I was able to get the app to display "Deuce" when both player's score = 40 but I couldnt figure out how to write the rest of the code. I edited the post and added the code I was able to write. Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: I edited my answer and provided the code for assessing scores. You should look at it and understand it carefully; if you do so, you'll be able to write the code for game wins on your own. It should almost be the same format: check if the wins are at least 6, and see if A is ahead by two games, one game, or tied, and perform actions accordingly.

Comment: @Giri06 No problem, glad I could be of help.